# Steps to simplify this boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

How do you simplify: ~A*B+A*~C+B*~C to A * ~C + B * ~A

I tried the distributive law but I end up going in circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equivalence is well known and called the [Consensus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem).

It can be proven as follows:

$$A'B + AC' + BC' \overset{Adjacency}{=}A'B + AC' + ABC' +A'BC' \overset{Absorption (2x)}{=}A'B + AC' $$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\bar{a}\,b+a\,\bar{c}+b\,\bar{c}&=
\bar{a}\,b\,(c+\bar{c})+a\,\bar{c}\,(b+\bar{b})+b\,\bar{c}\,(a+\bar{a})
\\
&=
\bar{a}\,b\,c+\bar{a}\,b\,\bar{c}+a\,\bar{c}\,b+a\,\bar{c}\,\bar{b}
\\
&=
\bar{a}\,b\,(c+\bar{c})+a\,\bar{c}\,(b+\bar{b})
\\
&=
\bar{a}\,b+a\,\bar{c}
.
\end{align}

**Edit**

This simplification can be demonstrated with
the unit-distance cube:

[image]